# Wait an asynchronous operation complete android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I'm begining with Android development. I have an asynchronous operation, but my intention is wait the operation is completed, and after that, continue the execution of my program.
I have used AsyncTask, and all its methods, but I got error, because on the onPreExecute method I want to show another Activity, so I guess I can't show another Activity. That's the reason I want to wait to complete the asynchronous operation.

Greetings

1st edit:
I've used AsyncTask(onPreExecute, doInBa..., onPost... ), but none method works. I understand how it works the AsyncTask class, but I want stop the execution when I invoke one asynchronous thirdparty method, because in the listener that needs, I change the value of a String variable X, and after invoke my method, that uses the thirdparty method, I use the variable X. I got an exeption because the variable hasn't updated.

Comment: What's the question? If you have an error, post it.

Comment: `onPostExecute` does that. You haven't said why that's not working and what you've tried to fix it.

Comment: So, **onPostExecute** I can go to other Activities???

Comment: what's the error? Please post your log!

Answer (score 1):

Please, read and follow example of [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You need to override onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

Not entirley sure what the question is but AsynTask has a method that you can call after everything has completed. A good practice is to have a dialog or a spinner showing that work is happening then dismiss it.

```
    class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //Do work

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            ShowProgress.dismiss();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PostExAct.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    }
```

In your on create:

```
ShowProgress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    new loadingTask().execute("params here");
```

This will show a loading dialog and while the work is being done then will be dismissed when the work is finished.

Comment: I understand yout example, but I want to wait an asynchronous operation complete, and that asynchronous operation show a new Activity, that can it happen?

Comment: Thats what `onPostExecute` is just put an intent to launch your new class. See edits.